Which Win32 API is responsible for Multiple Display support in Eclipse SWT
I understand that Eclipse SWT is dependent on Win32 APIs in the Windows operating system and GTK in the Linux operating system. As of now, Eclipse SWT in Windows supports the creation of multiple Display instances (multiple Java threads can create their own Display instances simultaneously), whereas in Linux, this is not the case.
I understand that GTK is not thread-safe and hence does not allow the creation of multiple GTK instances(UI threads)  per application, which in turn does not allow SWT to create multiple Displays in a multithreaded environment.
I tried to debug Display.java for SWT Linux where in it instantiates GTK . I tried to debug SWT code in windows but the CreateDisplay  method in Display.java is empty in windows SWT implementation.
Note : I checked CreateThread  API but is not used in SWT.
I am not talking about multiple windows creation because Window creation is equivalent to Shell creation in               SWT not the Display.
Is it SWT that is responsible for multiple Display support, or which underlying win32 APIs ?

Why do you want multiple Display instances? A single Display instance can handle multiple screens (called Monitors in SWT). Note that macOS also does not support multiple Display instances.

Note that the class name Display ended up being a poor choice of name, it isn't really anything to do with a particular physical display, rather the code responsible for coordinating all the SWT widgets and routing messages/event from the OS/Window system.

Yes . You are right . I just want to understand existing support for multiple Display instances creation in Windows OS . So that I can try to adopt same functionality in my application.

SWT just uses Windows APIs such as EnumDisplayMonitors and MonitorFromWindow to find the current displays. Creating a SWT Display instance doesn't create anything in Windows

I will reframe my question: I want to have multiple UI threads running in my application that will interact with OS resources simultaneously. I assume SWT in Windows already does this by handling additional synchronization with the help of Win32 APIs that is one Display instance corresponds to  one UI thread (Ref : https://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/documentation/2.0/html/plugins/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display.html)

That doc is saying you can use multiple Display instances, one per physical screen. For a particular screen there is only a single UI thread. Other threads use Display.asyncExec or Display.syncExec to run UI code on the single UI thread.

I did not get exact API from win32 .
But I got a hint from here which says to enhance performance, access to graphics device interface (GDI) objects (such as palettes, device contexts, regions, and the like) is not serialized . Which means Win32 is responsible for allowing SWT to spawn multiple threads to access OS resources like GDIP and SWT  have implemented required synchronization to handle multiple Display concept.
